# i have migrated angular project from one computer to another and when I run `npm i` it gives me these errors

Tags: angular, project

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file /home/germanus/Documents/Angular_projects/demoproj/package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0 while parsing near '...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/germanus/.npm/_logs/2021-04-17T09_15_03_006Z-debug.log
```

Comment: The error tells you the package file is malformed, so did you check what's in that file? Without a [mre] there's not much we can do.

Answer (score 2):

```
delete package-lock.json
npm clear -f cache
npm i
```

Comment: I made a mistake when I zipped myproject folder,some files were missing

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and then executing the following command could resolve your issue:

```
npm install
```

It should re-generate the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file.